# How can I use sandbox's webhooks and transactions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

How can I use webhooks on the sandbox? I'm using the Ruby Official SDK. I'm following this workflow:

1. I start a payment using `intent: 'sale'` and `payer: {payment_method: 'paypal'}`
2. Redirect to Paypal
3. Customer approve payment and is redirected back to my site
4. Execute payment

I can see that the buyer account has this transaction. I can also see that the seller received the transaction amount, but some things don't seem to work:

1. The app never receives the webhook call, even though the server contains a valid SSL certificate.
2. Transactions are never listed under "Transactions".

I also just noticed that when I try to create a new user account, a "Webhooks Simulator" link appears on the sidebar, but it rejects my URL, even though it is valid: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xjewf2r5xtwm797/2015-03-10%20at%2012.55%20PM.png

Am I missing something? Do these features (webhooks and transactions) require some specific payment method?

Answer (score -2):

So what is your funding source? echeck or credit card, for CC, you should see webhooks immediately. Your payment is valid, there's no special setup needed for using webhooks on sandbox. Have you tested the same thing on LIVE?